# Tengo problemas con certificados digitales con java

Tags: genexus15

Estoy consumiento un URL tipo HTPPS pero me sale este error:

Error descripción Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Ya carque el certificado en el archivo cacerts y tambien lo agregue en las propiedades del TOMCAT

Estoy trabajando con Genexus 15 y java.

Espero su apoyo gracias.